# my yeoman generator won't copy files

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am making a web app using yeoman and I'm stuck in creating a generator. The problem is that it won't copy files to the output folder.

Here's my code:

```
'use strict';
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var yeoman = require('yeoman-generator');
var yosay = require('yosay');
var chalk = require('chalk');
var wiredep = require('wiredep');

module.exports=yeoman.extend({

  scaffoldFolders: function(){
      this.mkdir("app");
      this.mkdir("app/css");
      this.mkdir("app/sections");
      this.mkdir("build");
  },

  initializing: function(){
    this.pkg=require('../../package.json');
  },

  prompting: function() {
    var done = this.async();

    this.log(yosay(
      'Welcome to the marvelous ' + chalk.red('generator-palmyra') + ' generator!'
    ));

    var prompts = [{
       type: 'checkbox',
       name: 'mainframeworks',
       message:'Would you like AngularJS or JQuery ?',
       choices: [{
         name: 'Angular',
         value: 'includeAngular',
         checked: true
        }, {
         name: 'JQuery',
         value: 'includeJQuery',
         checked: true
        }]
      },
    {
       type: 'checkbox',
       name: 'features',
       message:'What more front-end frameworks would you like ?',
       choices: [{
         name: 'Sass',
         value: 'includeSass',
         checked: true
    }, {
        name: 'Bootstrap',
        value: 'includeBootstrap',
        checked: true
    }, {
        name: 'Modernizr',
        value: 'includeModernizr',
        checked: true
      }]
    }
  ];


  this.prompt(prompts, function (answers) {
  var features = answers.features;
  var mainframeworks = answers.mainframeworks;
  var hasFeature = function (feat) {
     return features.indexOf(feat) !== -1;
  };
  var hasMainframeworks = function (mainframework) {
     return mainframeworks.indexOf(mainframework) !== -1;
  };
// manually deal with the response, get back and store the results.
  this.includeSass = hasFeature('includeSass');
  this.includeBootstrap = hasFeature('includeBootstrap');
  this.includeModernizr = hasFeature('includeModernizr');
  this.includeAngular = hasMainframeworks('includeAngular');
  this.includeJQuery = hasMainframeworks('includeJQuery');
  done();
}.bind(this));
},



  writing() {

    gulpfile= function(){
    this.fs.copy(
      this.templatePath('gulpfile.js'),
      this.destinationPath('gulpfile.js')
                );
                        },
    packageJSON= function () {
      this.fs.copy(
    this.templatePath('_package.json'),
    this.destinationPath('package.json')
  );
                              },
    git= function () {
      this.fs.copy(
       this.templatePath('gitignore'),
       this.destinationPath('.gitignore')
                   );
      this.fs.copy(
      this.templatePath('gitattributes'),
      this.destinationPath('.gitattributes')
                   );
                     },
      bower= function () {
                          var bower = {
                            name: this._.slugify(this.appname),
                            private: true,
                            dependencies: {}
                          };
                          if (this.includeBootstrap) {
                            var bs = 'bootstrap' + (this.includeSass ? '-sass' : '');
                            bower.dependencies[bs] = '~3.3.1';
                          }
                          if (this.includeModernizr) {
                            bower.dependencies.modernizr = '~2.8.1';
                          }
                      if (this.includeAngular) {
                        bower.dependencies.angular = '~1.3.15';
                      }
                      if (this.includeJQuery) {
                        bower.dependencies.jquery = '~2.1.1';
                      }
                        this.fs.copy(
                            this.templatePath('bowerrc'),
                            this.destinationPath('.bowerrc')
                          );
                          this.write('bower.json', JSON.stringify(bower, null, 2));
                        },
      jshint= function () {
      this.fs.copy(
      this.templatePath('jshintrc'),
      this.destinationPath('.jshintrc')
                  );
                          },
     mainStylesheet= function () {
                             var css = 'main';
                             if (this.includeSass) {
                               css += '.scss';
                             } else {
                               css += '.css';
                             }
                         this.copy(css, 'app/styles/' + css);
                                 },
    writeIndex= function () {
                                 this.indexFile = this.src.read('index.html');
                                 this.indexFile = this.engine(this.indexFile, this);
                                 // wire Bootstrap plugins
                                 if (this.includeBootstrap) {
                                   var bs = '/bower_components/';
                                   if (this.includeSass) {
                                     bs += 'bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/';
                                   } else {
                                     bs += 'bootstrap/js/';
                                   }
                                   this.indexFile = this.appendScripts(this.indexFile, 'scripts/plugins.js', [
                                     bs + 'affix.js',
                                     bs + 'alert.js',
                                     bs + 'dropdown.js',
                                     bs + 'tooltip.js',
                                     bs + 'modal.js',
                                     bs + 'transition.js',
                                     bs + 'button.js',
                                     bs + 'popover.js',
                                     bs + 'carousel.js',
                                     bs + 'scrollspy.js',
                                     bs + 'collapse.js',
                                     bs + 'tab.js'
                                   ]);
                                 }
                                 this.indexFile = this.appendFiles({
                                   html: this.indexFile,
                                   fileType: 'js',
                                   optimizedPath: 'scripts/main.js',
                                   sourceFileList: ['scripts/main.js']
                                 });
                                 this.write('app/index.html', this.indexFile);
                               },
                               app= function () {
                               this.copy('main.js', 'app/scripts/main.js');
                               }
                             },
   install: function () {
    var howToInstall =
      '\nAfter running ' +
      chalk.yellow.bold('npm install & bower install') +
      ', inject your' +
      '\nfront end dependencies by running ' +
      chalk.yellow.bold('gulp wiredep') +
      '.';
    if (this.options['skip-install']) {
      this.log(howToInstall);
      return;
    }
    this.installDependencies();
    this.on('end', function () {
      var bowerJson = this.dest.readJSON('bower.json');
      // wire Bower packages to .html
      wiredep({
        bowerJson: bowerJson,
        directory: 'bower_components',
        exclude: ['bootstrap-sass', 'bootstrap.js'],
        ignorePath: /^(\.\.\/)*\.\./,
        src: 'app/index.html'
      });
      if (this.includeSass) {
        // wire Bower packages to .scss
        wiredep({
          bowerJson: bowerJson,
          directory: 'bower_components',
          ignorePath: /^(\.\.\/)+/,
          src: 'app/styles/*.scss'
        });
      }
    }.bind(this));
  }
});
```

I think the problem is in the writing method. I also wanted to ask where to go next? Or did I pass a fundamental step toward learning web dev

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If so, please share them.

Comment: no error ... when i run it with yeoman ... the prompt methode works : asking me if i want to use angular or jquery ... after filling the options ... it just ends there

Answer (score 1):

i removed the var done =async() and replaced "this.prompt" by "return this.prompt"
most of the files are copied ... but there is still more invalid code ::

Comment: this happened to me also.  Had a done = this.async() that snuck in from some pasted code.  It was preventing files from being written!

Answer (score 0):

if you format your code, you'll see the `writing` function isn't doing anything. It declares a bunch of sub-functions, but doesn't run anyone.

I think the issue is you want an object but instead wrote a function: `writing() {}` instead of `writing: {}`.

I did a quick fix of the code, but didn't test it out. So there might be further syntax issue, but it should roughly look like this:

```js
'use strict';
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var yeoman = require('yeoman-generator');
var yosay = require('yosay');
var chalk = require('chalk');
var wiredep = require('wiredep');

module.exports = yeoman.extend({
    scaffoldFolders: function() {
        this.mkdir('app');
        this.mkdir('app/css');
        this.mkdir('app/sections');
        this.mkdir('build');
    },

    initializing: function() {
        this.pkg = require('../../package.json');
    },

    prompting: function() {
        var done = this.async();

        this.log(
            yosay(
                'Welcome to the marvelous ' +
                    chalk.red('generator-palmyra') +
                    ' generator!'
            )
        );

        var prompts = [
            {
                type: 'checkbox',
                name: 'mainframeworks',
                message: 'Would you like AngularJS or JQuery ?',
                choices: [
                    {
                        name: 'Angular',
                        value: 'includeAngular',
                        checked: true,
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'JQuery',
                        value: 'includeJQuery',
                        checked: true,
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                type: 'checkbox',
                name: 'features',
                message: 'What more front-end frameworks would you like ?',
                choices: [
                    {
                        name: 'Sass',
                        value: 'includeSass',
                        checked: true,
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Bootstrap',
                        value: 'includeBootstrap',
                        checked: true,
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Modernizr',
                        value: 'includeModernizr',
                        checked: true,
                    },
                ],
            },
        ];

        this.prompt(
            prompts,
            function(answers) {
                var features = answers.features;
                var mainframeworks = answers.mainframeworks;
                var hasFeature = function(feat) {
                    return features.indexOf(feat) !== -1;
                };
                var hasMainframeworks = function(mainframework) {
                    return mainframeworks.indexOf(mainframework) !== -1;
                };
                // manually deal with the response, get back and store the results.
                this.includeSass = hasFeature('includeSass');
                this.includeBootstrap = hasFeature('includeBootstrap');
                this.includeModernizr = hasFeature('includeModernizr');
                this.includeAngular = hasMainframeworks('includeAngular');
                this.includeJQuery = hasMainframeworks('includeJQuery');
                done();
            }.bind(this)
        );
    },

    writing: {
        gulpfile: function() {
            this.fs.copy(
                this.templatePath('gulpfile.js'),
                this.destinationPath('gulpfile.js')
            );
        },
        packageJSON: function() {
            this.fs.copy(
                this.templatePath('_package.json'),
                this.destinationPath('package.json')
            );
        },
        git: function() {
            this.fs.copy(
                this.templatePath('gitignore'),
                this.destinationPath('.gitignore')
            );
            this.fs.copy(
                this.templatePath('gitattributes'),
                this.destinationPath('.gitattributes')
            );
        },
        bower: function() {
            var bower = {
                name: this._.slugify(this.appname),
                private: true,
                dependencies: {},
            };
            if (this.includeBootstrap) {
                var bs = 'bootstrap' + (this.includeSass ? '-sass' : '');
                bower.dependencies[bs] = '~3.3.1';
            }
            if (this.includeModernizr) {
                bower.dependencies.modernizr = '~2.8.1';
            }
            if (this.includeAngular) {
                bower.dependencies.angular = '~1.3.15';
            }
            if (this.includeJQuery) {
                bower.dependencies.jquery = '~2.1.1';
            }
            this.fs.copy(this.templatePath('bowerrc'), this.destinationPath('.bowerrc'));
            this.write('bower.json', JSON.stringify(bower, null, 2));
        },
        jshint: function() {
            this.fs.copy(
                this.templatePath('jshintrc'),
                this.destinationPath('.jshintrc')
            );
        },
        mainStylesheet: function() {
            var css = 'main';
            if (this.includeSass) {
                css += '.scss';
            } else {
                css += '.css';
            }
            this.copy(css, 'app/styles/' + css);
        },
        writeIndex: function() {
            this.indexFile = this.src.read('index.html');
            this.indexFile = this.engine(this.indexFile, this);
            // wire Bootstrap plugins
            if (this.includeBootstrap) {
                var bs = '/bower_components/';
                if (this.includeSass) {
                    bs += 'bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/';
                } else {
                    bs += 'bootstrap/js/';
                }
                this.indexFile = this.appendScripts(
                    this.indexFile,
                    'scripts/plugins.js',
                    [
                        bs + 'affix.js',
                        bs + 'alert.js',
                        bs + 'dropdown.js',
                        bs + 'tooltip.js',
                        bs + 'modal.js',
                        bs + 'transition.js',
                        bs + 'button.js',
                        bs + 'popover.js',
                        bs + 'carousel.js',
                        bs + 'scrollspy.js',
                        bs + 'collapse.js',
                        bs + 'tab.js',
                    ]
                );
            }
            this.indexFile = this.appendFiles({
                html: this.indexFile,
                fileType: 'js',
                optimizedPath: 'scripts/main.js',
                sourceFileList: ['scripts/main.js'],
            });
            this.write('app/index.html', this.indexFile);
        },
        app: function() {
            this.copy('main.js', 'app/scripts/main.js');
        },
    },

    install: function() {
        var howToInstall =
            '\nAfter running ' +
            chalk.yellow.bold('npm install & bower install') +
            ', inject your' +
            '\nfront end dependencies by running ' +
            chalk.yellow.bold('gulp wiredep') +
            '.';
        if (this.options['skip-install']) {
            this.log(howToInstall);
            return;
        }
        this.installDependencies();
        this.on(
            'end',
            function() {
                var bowerJson = this.dest.readJSON('bower.json');
                // wire Bower packages to .html
                wiredep({
                    bowerJson: bowerJson,
                    directory: 'bower_components',
                    exclude: ['bootstrap-sass', 'bootstrap.js'],
                    ignorePath: /^(\.\.\/)*\.\./,
                    src: 'app/index.html',
                });
                if (this.includeSass) {
                    // wire Bower packages to .scss
                    wiredep({
                        bowerJson: bowerJson,
                        directory: 'bower_components',
                        ignorePath: /^(\.\.\/)+/,
                        src: 'app/styles/*.scss',
                    });
                }
            }.bind(this)
        );
    },
});
```

Comment: i made those changes ... it's the same issue ... the files won't copy in the new directory